# Exercise for 1Z0-804 exam. deadlock, livelock, starvation or race condition?

Tags: java

I'm learning for 1Z0-804 exam and found an exercise on the internet and I don't understand it. Sounds like this:

> Sam has designed an application. It segregates tasks that are critical and executed frequently from tasks that are non critical and executed less frequently. He has prioritized these tasks based on their criticality and frequency of execution. After close scrutiny, he finds that the tasks designed to be non critical are rarely getting executed. From what kind of problem is the application suffering?

This are the options:

```
A. race condition
B. starvation
C. deadlock
D. livelock
```

Which one is true and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one do *you* think is true, and why? Which ones do you think are false, and why? Tell us what you think, so we can help you with what you don't understand.

Comment: I think option `B.` is true. Because I read that `Starvation describes a situation where a thread is unable to gain regular access to shared resources and is unable to make progress.` Is that correct?

Comment: Sounds like it!

Comment: @AndyTurner So is it this the correct answer?

Comment: If I may, why are you not passing the Java 8 version (1Z0-809 I believe) ? 1Z0-804 is on Java 7

Comment: Yes, 1Z0-804 is on Java 7. 1Z0-809 is the next that will take. Is `B.` the correct answer?

Comment: @IoanaP. you will need to pass an upgrade, if you are preparing for it, you could do directly the 1Z0-809 as it should be the same with Stream API (that prevent to pay twice ;) ). To be honnest, I have just buy the book for 1Z0-809 so I am not yet the best on that matter ;)

Comment: @AxelH Thnaks a lot for your advice AxelH.

Comment: @IoanaP. this need confirmation, You might need to do the upgrade of the OCA 7 first to be able to pass the OCP 8, I am not sure, so check it first. I stop chatting, sorry ;).

Comment: If is needed, please confirm to me. Thanks